# How to make query without having generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I'll start with piece of code:

```
var objectType = typeof(Department); // Department is entity class from linqdatacontext

using (var dataContext = new DataModel.ModelDataContext())
{
    var entity = Expression.Parameter(objectType, "model");
    var keyValue = Expression.Property(entity, "Id");
    var pkValue = Expression.Constant(reader.Value);
    var cond = Expression.Equal(keyValue, pkValue);
    var table = dataContext.GetTable(objectType);
    ... // and here i don't how to proceed
}
```

I am not even sure if i am building that expression correctly. However simply put, i need to call dynamically `SingleOrDefault()` on that table to find entity by primary key. Every example i had found is using generic variant of `GetTable<>()`, but i cannot use that obviously. I am probably overlooking something...

Comment: Why not just make this code itself generic?

Comment: Well i don't want that, because i have there like 30 entities that i need to retrieve with this. That would be sort of messy and tiresome.

Comment: But if the code itself is generic, then you still need just one method, unless I'm missing something. (In which case `dynamic` is perhaps the solution, but I still don't see why here).

Comment: I don't know much about `dynamic` keyword. Where do you see any generic code ? I have just classic Type there and value of primary key, nothing more.

Comment: Ah, so in the "real" version, the setting of `objectType` is elsewhere in code. Yes, that'll stop generics working for you if the calling code doesn't have an appropriate instance or is able to hard-code the type.
Look at @SteveDanner 's answer then, the use of `dynamic` in the Where shows how to call properties without compile-time knowledge of the type. This will be useful later on, though I think your problem is slightly different.

Comment: Yeah, but see my comment there. There is none Where method for non-generic `GetTable` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I build expression trees, I like to start off with an example of what I'm building:

```
() => dataContext.GetTable<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(entity => entity.Id == 1);
```

From that, we can easily dissect the target expression. You are partway there; you just need to include a call to the `GetTable` method in the expression tree and then build an outer lambda expression to call the whole thing:

```
using(var dataContext = new DataModel.ModelDataContext())
{
    var getTableCall = Expression.Call(
        Expression.Constant(dataContext),
        "GetTable",
        new[] { entityType });

    var entity = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

    var idCheck = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(entity, "Id"),
        Expression.Constant(reader.Value));

    var idCheckLambda = Expression.Lambda(idCheck, entity);

    var singleOrDefaultCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "SingleOrDefault",
        new[] { entityType },
        getTableCall,
        Expression.Quote(idCheckLambda));

    var singleOrDefaultLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
        Expression.Convert(singleOrDefaultCall, typeof(object)));

    var singleOrDefaultFunction = singleOrDefaultLambda.Compile();

    return singleOrDefaultFunction();    
}
```

We have to convert the `SingleOrDefault` call to have a return type of object so it can serve as the body of the `Func<object>` function.

(Untested)

**Edit: Parameterizing the data context and value**

Now we are building this function:

```
(dataContext, value) => dataContext.GetTable<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(entity => entity.Id == value);
```

You would change the constants to parameters and add those parameters to the function you compile:

```
var dataContextParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ModelDataContext), "dataContext");

var valueParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

var getTableCall = Expression.Call(
    dataContextParameter,
    "GetTable",
    new[] { entityType });

var entity = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

var idCheck = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(entity, "Id"),
    valueParameter);

var idCheckLambda = Expression.Lambda(idCheck, entity);

var singleOrDefaultCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "SingleOrDefault",
    new[] { entityType },
    getTableCall,
    Expression.Quote(idCheckLambda));

var singleOrDefaultLambda =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<ModelDataContext, object, object>>(
        Expression.Convert(singleOrDefaultCall, typeof(object)),
        dataContextParameter,
        valueParameter);

var singleOrDefaultFunction = singleOrDefaultLambda.Compile();

// Usage

using(var dataContext = new DataModel.ModelDataContext())
{
    return singleOrDefaultFunction(dataContext, reader.Value);    
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks nasty :) I will definitely try it later, i need to do some errands now. I will let you know than if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it works fine, thank you very much. Now i am thinking about some optimization, because there will be a lot of calls to this and compiling this every time can go bad. And there is also problem with that `dataContext` being disposed at the end of using, so it cannot be used like constant. I am trying something with `Expression.Variable`, but not sure how to use it properly. It would be great to have precompiled function where can put parameters with dataContext and Value and than execute it to retrieve result.

Comment: You are genius :) Thank you, that's exactly what i need. Although it goes bad in making `Expression.Equal` because `Id` property is type of `Int32` and i am passing `object` there. But that's no big deal, i can manage that, in this case it's good enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4, you could try casting your returned objects as `dynamic`, so you could then query like this.

```
using (var dataContext = new DataModel.ModelDataContext())
{
   var entity = Expression.Parameter(objectType, "model");
   var keyValue = Expression.Property(entity, "Id");
   var pkValue = Expression.Constant(reader.Value);
   var cond = Expression.Equal(keyValue, pkValue);
   var table = dataContext.GetTable(objectType);

   var result = table.Where(ent => ((dynamic)ent).SomeField == "SomeValue");
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am using .NET 4. That would be nice, but problem starts at table variable. There is no Where method, because it's no typed or for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure as to the whole of your problem (and I suspect the answer about `dynamic` is going to solve part of what will come up too). Still, just to answer:

> Every example i had found is using generic variant of GetTable<>(), but i cannot use that obviously

For any `T`, `Table<T>` implements (among other interfaces) `ITable<T>` and `ITable`. The former is generically typed, the latter not.

The form `GetTable<T>()` returns such a `Table<T>`. However, the form `GetTable(Type t)` returns an `ITable`. Since `ITable` inherits from `IQueryable` you can query it. If you need to do something with that query that would normally require knowledge of the type (such as comparing on a given property) then `dynamic` as per the previous answer given by Steve Danner allows that to happen.

Comment: Ok, but i am still probably missing something in this. How can i query `IQueryable` without knowing type there ? When i use generic `GetTable<T>`, than i get possible methods like Where and Select. But with non-generic `GetTable(Type t)` there is nothing. I don't how could i use `dynamic` in there (_mostly because that keyword is still unknown for me_)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using Reflection and the [LINQ dynamic query library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), personally.

You can get the list of all the keys for a table with `dataContext.Mapping.GetMetaType(objectType).IdentityMembers`, then access the data with something along the lines of `dataContext.GetTable(objectType).Where(key.Name + "==@0", id)`.

Obviously, I left out a few steps in there - if you have multiple keys, you'll need to build a fuller predicate with a loop over `.IdentityMembers`, and if you always just have the one key, you can use .First() on it.  I haven't tested it either, but it should be pretty close.   It'd probably be 6-7 lines of code total - I can write it up (and test) if you need it.

---

Edit: The LINQ Dynamic Query Library can be downloaded from Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx - just include DynamicLINQ.cs in your project and you're good.

Comment: Still the same problem. Non generic version of `GetTable` does not has the `Where` method.

Comment: @FredyC: I forgot that I had installed a separate LINQ Dynamic Query Library. Oops.  Link to it has been added.